# Complexifying the integral questions

Tags: self-learning

I'm self-studying MIT 18.03. I have come across a topic, the complexification of integrals, and would like to do practice questions involving this topic. I cannot find any questions pertaining to the topic in any calculus textbook, or differential equation textbook I have. Can someone point me to a textbook or other resource which contains questions on this topic?

Comment: The book "Fundamentals of Complex Analysis" by E B Saff and Arthur David Snyder is pretty good.

Comment: I don't think complex contour integrals are intended here. Can you please be explicit about what "complexification of integrals" means to you? My guess is that you want to play with things like $\int e^{ix}\,dx$ and $\int e^{ix}f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not exactly sure which type Professor Mattuck meant in the lecture, he called it complexifying the integral. He used the formula $e^(ix)=cos(x)+isinx$ to solve the integral $int(e^(-x)cos(x)dx)$

Comment: Wow!  I don't think I've seen this before... pretty cute technique. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Integration_by_Complexifying

Comment: "Complexification" sounds like it's just a matter of replacing $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}2$. Then$$\int e^{-x}\cos(x)\,dx=\frac12\int (e^{(-1+i)x} + e^{(-1-i)x}) \, dx$$